# Creating 3-way tables: tabyl output sorting

Tags: r, janitor

I am trying to create a three-way tabyl and I am struggling to sort the columns and rows as I want. Here is the example:

```
library(janitor)
df <- data.frame(gender = c("f", "m", "m", "f", "m"),
                 age_group = factor(
                   c("35-45", "18-35", ">55", "45-55", ">55"), 
                   levels = c("18-35", "35-45", "45-55", ">55")),
                 bmi_group = factor(
                   c("18.5 - 25", "<18.5", "18.5 - 25", ">30", "25 - 30"),
                   levels = c("<18.5", "18.5 - 25", "25 - 30", ">30")),
                 stringsAsFactors = TRUE)


df %>%
  tabyl(bmi_group, age_group, gender, show_missing_levels = FALSE) %>%
  adorn_totals("row") %>%
  adorn_percentages("all") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 1) %>%
  adorn_ns %>%
  adorn_title
```

It gives me this:

[image]

I can't figure out how to sort entries in gender-specific tables by factor levels. The sorting is alphabetical right now.

Comment: Wonder if this is a bug that is not fixed (https://github.com/sfirke/janitor/issues/250). With two factors in `tabyl` this seems to work with order by factor. But not with three factors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch!  This was a [bug in the janitor package](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor/issues/379).  It was fixed in [version 2.1.0](http://sfirke.github.io/janitor/news/index.html#janitor-2-1-0-2021-01-05-2021-01-05), released in January 2021.  The same code above now results in output with columns and rows sorted by factor level:

```
$f
           age_group          
 bmi_group     35-45     45-55
 18.5 - 25 50.0% (1)  0.0% (0)
       >30  0.0% (0) 50.0% (1)
     Total 50.0% (1) 50.0% (1)

$m
           age_group          
 bmi_group     18-35       >55
     <18.5 33.3% (1)  0.0% (0)
 18.5 - 25  0.0% (0) 33.3% (1)
   25 - 30  0.0% (0) 33.3% (1)
     Total 33.3% (1) 66.7% (2)
```